How do I analyze the terminal input and output in Python while executing another script?
The idea behind the program I'm trying to create is a file that can help grade programming exercises while allowing the students freedom to meet the tasks without telling them exactly how to accomplish them. I would like to be able to use a program to analyze the inputs and outputs to the terminal as they occur rather than analyzing everything in a stdout after the program has finished running.
I've been bouncing through threads trying different approaches involving subprocess.run, open, with subprocess.Popen(...) as proc:, exec(), and pexpect. The code example I'll include here is the last one I felt was anywhere close to usable (even if it's not where I want it to be).
The problem with the way this code works is that it only compares the expected result to the final stdout which is just a huge string that could be hardcoded and provide a false pass. Instead of providing an entire text file as an input using the command "script < txt_file" I would like to be able to provide just one line of input at a time and capture the output at that moment so that I can see if each input is yielding a response as well as being able to potentially isolate specific areas to look at for more difficult exercises.
import os
import subprocess

cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
expected_input = f"{cwd}/expected_input.txt"
expected_path = f"{cwd}/expected_output.txt"

def get_expected_output(file_path):
    return_str = ""
    with open(file_path, "r") as temp_file:
        for line in temp_file:
            if not line:
                break
            return_str += line
    return return_str

def main():
    expected_output = get_expected_output(expected_path)
    for x in range(1,4):
        test_path = f"{cwd}/test{x}.py"
        with subprocess.Popen(f"python {test_path} < {expected_input}", 
                              stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                              shell=True,  
                              text=True
                              ) as proc:
            std_out, std_err = proc.communicate()
            if std_out != expected_output:
                print(f"Expected: \n{expected_output} \n\nActual: \n{std_out}")
                print(f"Take a look at student {x}'s code")
            else:
                print(f"Student {x} finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Ex1 (A normal passing code):
import sys

def main():
    while(True):
        print("Please enter a number or type exit")
        user_input = float(input())
        if user_input == 'exit':
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print(f"{user_input} x 2 = {user_input*2}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Ex2 (A hardcoded series of print statements that still yields a pass):
print("Please enter a number or type exit")
print("1.0 x 2 = 2.0")
print("Please enter a number or type exit")
print("2.0 x 2 = 4.0")
print("Please enter a number or type exit")
print("3.0 x 2 = 6.0")
print("Please enter a number or type exit")


Use pexpect to automate interactive programs, not subprocess.

@Barmar Could you provide any simple examples? I was trying pexpect earlier and wasn't finding success. Their documentation said that spawn objects don't work in Windows, and the examples section of their docs don't actually have any code snippets to follow with.

No, sorry, I've not done any programming with it myself.
